# Display points of interset on Amchart line-graph

Tags: amcharts

I am using the amcharts' adjustBalloonText function to display values for given dates. Certain dates also display extra text (notes to explain irregular values).

Without hovering the cursor over the specific dates containing the extra text, it's impossible to quickly identify these points on the line-graph. Is there anyway that I can highlight these points on the graph (e.g. change the shape or colour of the graph.bullets on the chart)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify shape for each bullet individually use graph's [`bulletField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletField) property. Similarly, to modify bullet size use [`bulletSizeField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletSizeField). This way you can specify which field in data sets bullet type and size respectively.

If chart finds such field(s) in data point data, it will use these settings instead of default graph's bullet settings: `bullet` and `bulletSize`:

Here's working chart to illustrate that:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletSize": 25
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 9,
    "bulletField": "bullet",
    "bulletSizeField": "bulletSize",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "categoryField": "country"
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```

There's currently no way to change color of individual bullets, unless you would like to go through some other workarounds, like using two graphs: one regular and the other for displaying highlighted out bullets.

Here's a link to demo for the above workaround, just in case:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/08f94aac4f5d4c071850cd7ae0c758f9

Comment: How would you change the colour of individual bullets using the line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom example - via the generateChartData function?

Comment: Well, it would work the same way: generateChartData function would need to apply some logic as to which data points to add `bullet`/`bulletSize` properties to. Also graphs would need `bulletField` and `bulletSizeField` properties added to.

Comment: Thanks for that. Link to demo - creating data dynamically: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpgvKY